# R Shiny: Multiple Conditional Panels with the same condition from CheckboxInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to design a shiny ui with conditionalPanel() which should be displayed or hidden when I select or deselect e.g. an a checkboxInput(). In the example below the it looks fine, but I still get following error messages twice when I call the shinyApp():

```
*Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used        
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1*
```

How can I use the input.topic1 for the conditions of multiple conditionalPanels without having error messages?

In my original code I have more elements and for each checkboxInput I get two error messages. Sometimes(inconsistent?!) the ui also just displays all the conditional panels and the checkboxInputs seem not to have any effect when clicked. Before addressing that I first want to solve the error messages that occur.

Sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

header<-dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id="sidebar_tabs",menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "Overview")))

body_overview<-tabItem(tabName = "Overview"                           
fluidRow(box(title ="Topic 1",width = 2,"Text",checkboxInput("topic1", "Display plot",TRUE)),
        box(title ="Topic 2",width = 2,"Text",checkboxInput("topic2", "Display plot",FALSE))),
fluidRow(
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic1 == true",box(title="Graph 1",footer="How did the customer equity develop?",width = 8,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(5)])))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic1 == true",box(title="Parameters 1",width = 4,dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),format = "mm/yyyy"))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic2 == true",box(title="Graph 2",footer="How did the customer equity develop?",width = 8,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(5)])))),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic2 == true",box(title="Parameters 1",width = 4,dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),format = "mm/yyyy"))))
)

body<-dashboardBody(tabItems(body_overview))
sdb_ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar,body)

shinyApp(ui = sdb_ui, server = function(input, output,session) {})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you get comes from `plotOutput` which expects a character string specifying the `outputId`. It's better to compute your plots on the server side. To avoid the warnings, you could do something like this:

```
body_overview<-tabItem(tabName = "Overview",                           
                   fluidRow(box(title ="Topic 1",width = 2,"Text",checkboxInput("topic1", "Display plot",TRUE)),
                            box(title ="Topic 2",width = 2,"Text",checkboxInput("topic2", "Display plot",FALSE))
                   ),
                   fluidRow(
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic1 == true",box(title="Graph 1",footer="How did the customer equity develop?",width = 8,plotOutput("hist1"))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic1 == true",box(title="Parameters 1",width = 4,dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),format = "mm/yyyy"))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic2 == true",box(title="Graph 2",footer="How did the customer equity develop?",width = 8,plotOutput("hist2"))),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.topic2 == true",box(title="Parameters 1",width = 4,dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),format = "mm/yyyy")))
                   )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$hist1 <- renderPlot(
        hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(5)])
    )
    output$hist2 <- renderPlot(
        hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(5)])
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = sdb_ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It also seems to solve the inconsistent display problem.